# How much does one percent of unemployment 'cost'? (Unemployment elasticity)

Tags: macroeconomics, gdp, elasticity, unemployment, minimum-wage

There is always debate that increasing minimum salary will pour in more money into the budget [as those who get minimum salary will spend them immediately](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/429/what-is-the-economic-purpose-of-increasing-the-minimum-wage#answer-515).

The counter argument is that increasing minimum salary will increase unemployment and it will bring all the downsides (sitting on benefits, less spending, crime,...)

I was wondering is there established 'elasticity' between unemployment to GDP e.g 1% raise in unemployment would reduce GDP growth by X%? I am sure it will differ from country to country and also change from 10% to 9% and from 2% to one will not be the same, still there should be some ratio or formula with wide margin?

**How much does rise of one percent in unemployment affect GBP?**

Comment: I am sure it depends on where the unemployment is as well, I.e. going from 1 to 2% may change a different amount than from 8 to 9%, and also how you measure unemployment